# Python Flask app stops running without any error messages on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, instantiation, pythonanywhere

The app was running fine. Then I changed the content of an .env file. Since then, the app doesn’t run anymore and it's not the content of this .env file that causes the problem as you can read below. There are 3 classes. App, Amazon, Helper. They're all in the same package "/api". The .env sits in the parent directory.

The Helper class, gets imported into the Amazon class. The import seems to have no problems (I tried everything from the support page: [DebuggingImportError](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/)). The Helper class seems to get instantiated correctly. But after that, the program seems to stop completely. Nothing happens. Not even error messages. Nothing.

I think the code is OK. Because it was beforehand (and I just changed the .env) and up to this Helper class instantiation it runs. 3 hours I tried to debug. I can’t find an error. And like I said, there are no Error messages. Not in the console nor in the error log.

I tried not to use dotenv (because I changed the .env file and thought this could cause the problem) and hardcoded the content of the .env file. But still no reaction.
I surrounded almost everything with try statements to find an error. Nothing.

I am wondering about the fact, that there are no error messages whatsoever.

Can there be any server issues causing this effect?

#### The important part of the Amazon class:

```
import logging
import os
from urllib.parse import urlencode

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

logging.basicConfig(level = logging.ERROR)

try:
    from api.Helper import Helper
except ImportError as e:
    loggin.error('IMPORT ERROR ' + e)




class Amazon:

    def __init__(self, country: str, category: str, search: str, percent: str,
             api_key: str) -> None:

    # As you can see below, this message gets logged
    logging.error("BEFORE HELPER INIT") 

    try:
        # On this point the program stops
        self.helper = Helper()
    except:
        # This doesn't get printed to the error log
        logging.error('ERROR HELPER INIT')

    # Neither does this message
    logging.error('HELPER' + self.helper)  

    if not self.helper.check_api_key(api_key):
        logging.error('WRONG API KEY')
        return

    self.country = country
    self.category = category
    self.search = search
    self.percent = percent
```

#### The important part of the Helper class:

```
 import logging
    import os
    from random import randrange
    from urllib import request
    from dotenv import load_dotenv

    try:
        project_folder = os.path.expanduser('..')
        load_dotenv(os.path.join(project_folder, '.env'))
    except:
        print('ERROR LOAD_DOTENV')

    logging.basicConfig(level = logging.ERROR)

    class Helper:

        API_KEY = ""

        def __init__(self):
            # This message gets printed to the error log
            logging.error('INIT HELPER')  
            try:
                Helper.API_KEY = '<api-key>' #os.getenv('API_KEY')
            except ValueError as e:
                logging.error("ERROR INIT HELPER " + e)
            except TypeError as e:
                logging.error("ERROR INIT HELPER " + e)
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error("ERROR INIT HELPER " + e)
            except:
                logging.error("ERROR INIT HELPER ")

        def check_api_key(self, key: str) -> bool:
            logging.error("CHECK_API_KEY()")

            if key == Helper.API_KEY:
               logging.error("API-KEY:" + Helper.API_KEY)
                logging.error("KEY:" + key)
                return True
            logging.error('HELPER FALSE')
            return False
```

#### Part of Error log:

```
2021-01-08 18:29:31,308: BEFORE HELPER INIT
2021-01-08 18:29:31,309: INIT HELPER: <api-key>
2021-01-08 18:30:59,875: BEFORE HELPER INIT
2021-01-08 18:30:59,875: INIT HELPER: <api-key>
2021-01-08 18:33:05,909: BEFORE HELPER INIT
2021-01-08 18:34:14,390: BEFORE HELPER INIT
2021-01-08 18:34:14,391: INIT HELPER: <api-key>
2021-01-08 18:36:50,071: BEFORE HELPER INIT
2021-01-08 18:36:50,072: INIT HELPER: <api-key>
2021-01-08 18:41:47,026: BEFORE HELPER INIT
2021-01-08 18:41:47,027: INIT HELPER: <api-key>
```

Comment: you have wrong indentation in `Amazon` - or is it only typo when you copy code?

Comment: do you use free account on `PythonAnywhere` ? As I remeber it freezes page for 8h every day - because it is free - but I don't know if they still do this.

Comment: @furas it's only the copied code. In the original it is correct. It is not a free Account. And if it was, the program wouldn't run at all.

Comment: error and code doesn't give any clue what can be problem - you may only ask admins of PythonAnywhere for help

Comment: @furas PythonAnywhere dev here -- I think you might be confusing us with another service, we don't freeze free websites at all; they can operate 24 hours a day.

Comment: @foofourtyone -- you say that your site "stops running", but could you give some more details of what you mean by that?  Do you get an error page when you visit it?  Or is it hanging and just not returning a page?  Or something else?

Comment: @GilesThomas I wasn't sure - but I tried to check it after writing my comment. Probably it was free account on Heroku or OpenShift.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I had a simple solution. I just copied the code from Helper into Amazon and deleted the Helper. May be it was a problem with the __init__ of Helper class.